# rewrite sql query to hql hibernate query

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

I have an sql query which should be converted to HQL. I tried to convert it but I get this error :

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token

How can I rewrite this sql query to HQL query?

```
select ProductsBase.PRODUCT_ID,
ProductsBase.PRODUCT_NAME,
ProductsBase.LIST_PRICE,
CategoryTranslations.CATEGORY_NAME,
CategoryTranslations.CATEGORY_ID
from products_base         ProductsBase,
CATEGORY_TRANSLATIONS CategoryTranslations,
PRODUCT_TRANSLATIONS  ProductTranslations
where CategoryTranslations.CATEGORY_ID(+) = ProductsBase.CATEGORY_ID
and ProductTranslations.PRODUCT_ID(+) = ProductsBase.PRODUCT_ID
and CategoryTranslations.LANGUAGE = 'EN'
and ProductTranslations.LANGUAGE = 'EN'
and ProductsBase.product_id in
(select PRODUCT_ID
from (SELECT OrderItems.product_id,
max(OrderItems.quantity) as Items_Ordered
FROM order_items OrderItems, products_base ProductsBase
WHERE ProductsBase.product_id = OrderItems.product_id
GROUP By OrderItems.product_id,
ProductsBase.Product_Name,
ProductsBase.category_id
ORDER BY Items_Ordered DESC))
```

I tried this HQL but I got error :

> QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token

```
from ProductsBase pr , ProductTranslations prt ,CategoryTranslations ct where ct.productCategoriesBase.categoryId = pr.categoryId and pr.productId = prt.productsBase.productId and ct.language ='EN' and prt.language = 'EN' and pr.productId in
( select subquery.prId from ( select oi.productsBase.productId prId , max(oi.quantity) qoi from OrderItems oi , ProductsBase prin where oi.productsBase.productId = prin.productId group by oi.productsBase.productId , prin.productName , prin.categoryId order by qoi DESC) as subquery )
```

What should I do? How can I fix my problem with this HQL or what HQL query I can replace with above?

Comment: Try to use not all your entities first time. Try to join first two, check SQL query, if it will be correct, - then add another one and check again. In that way you can build your entire query.

Comment: I did this. I sepratly test every parts of query and they were true but when I test all this parts together I get error. Specialy when I add subquery. @Lav

Comment: 1. Turn on hibernate SQL logging, to see what Hibernate really send to database, update your question with this output. 2. As you said, the problem in "IN" sentence. Try to replace it with "EXISTS". 3. Say us result )) I had the same problem and I solve it by using "EXISTS"

Comment: Show to us the full stracktrace of the error.